# Pink colour in the rendered image and video

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

[image]

I made this plane, it was completely fine in the 2.9 version but now i upgraded to 3.0 version, maybe it is due to that only.
It is showing a pinkish tint while other colors are there.

Comment: pink tint means that it has lost the image texture, try File > External Data > Find Missing Files

Comment: Looks as if you may have a HDRI image missing.